# Access 2010: Pad (y) a variable string length (x) to a predetermined total so that x+y=55

Tags: ms-access-2010, string-length, maxlength, variable-length, pad

I found plenty of advice on how to pad a string in `Access 2010` but none on how to pad a variable length string with spaces out to a predetermined total string length.

**Example:**

```
Total length = 55, 
if string len = 15, then pad " " x 40 (15+40=55)
if string len = 35, then pad " " x 20 (35+20=55) etc
```

I could write a function to do this but I want to know if there is one already built in!

Comment: As it happens, I want them after. However, there is a further twist that we are concatenating three columns from Excel into one string yet must maintain three 'pseudo-columns' so that PeopleSoft (which is expecting a single string from SalesForce whose's input we have hijacked) can unpack them neatly into three columns again.. (NOT my idea)

Answer (score 1):

A bit of math?

```
 [x] & space(55 - len([x]))
```

Comment: Couldn't make this work as supplied.. not sure why (possibly because the problem is a bit more complex than I initially indicated) and will get back to you if I do get it to work or when I've exhausted all avenues.     But really I wanted a word, like PAD() or SPACE() or something quick and easy. I have to hand this over to non-coders at some point so writing a FN is something I'd like to avoid.

Comment: That expr should always pad so long as `x` is < 55 chars long.  There is no single function to do it. (It *can* be done with `LSet` but thats an expression so cant be used in a query)

Comment: Hypothesis: since I'm concat'ing 3 cols and some are empty, its being asked to pad a negative amount!  Therefore it returns an error.

Comment: Fixed with a little help from my friends!  
SELECT
(MyTest.[Name1]) & SPACE(55-LEN(MyTest.[Name1]))
+ (MyTest.[Name2]) & SPACE(55-Nz(LEN(MyTest.[Name2]), 0))
+ (MyTest.[Name3]) & SPACE(55-LEN(MyTest.[Name3]))

FROM MyTest;

Answer (score 0):

There is a native function for this:

```
Dim Total   As String
Dim Content As String

Total = Space(55)
Content = "Some Content"
RSet Total = Content

Debug.Print Chr(34) & Total & Chr(34)
' Will return:
' "Some Content                                           "
```

or even simpler:

```
Dim Total   As String * 55
Dim Content As String

Content = "Some Content"
RSet Total = Content

Debug.Print Chr(34) & Total & Chr(34)
' Will return:
' "Some Content                                           "
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid writing code - hence the search for a predefined function or key word.  Thank for taking the time to comment though!

Comment: Oh. Effectively two lines of code ... how lazy can one be?

Comment: Such are most of my colleagues. Nice people with weird humour.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
(MyTest.[Name1]) & SPACE(55-LEN(MyTest.[Name1])) + 
(MyTest.[Name2]) & SPACE(55-Nz(LEN(MyTest.[Name2]), 0)) + 
(MyTest.[Name3]) & SPACE(55-LEN(MyTest.[Name3])) 
FROM MyTest;
```